# Discrete math and rules of inference

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I recently did this rules of inference/logic question and the method I used was different from the textbook so I was wondering if my work was correct?[image]

Comment: Would be good to learn the (much shorter) names of the reasons, such as "modus ponens", "modus tollens", et al.

Comment: Haha, yeah I should, but I am correct or did I do it wrong?

Comment: Your work is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$(p\to q) \wedge (q\to b)$ implies $p\to b$, but not the other way around.  Hence those two justifications are false as written.  Fortunately, you only need them in one direction, the one that is true.

Comment: so step 4 and 5 can't turn to step 6?

Comment: which two are wrong?

Comment: You used this justification in step 4 and step 6.  The steps are right, but your justifications are written incorrectly.